# How to return only the person names who belong to a group?

Tags: computational-linguistics, named-entity-recognition

I could classify words in all sentences in a text file as PERSON, LOCATION, ORGANIZATION etc. using Stanford's Named Entity Recognition. But how to extract names of a specific group of persons (eg: All borrowers names)?

Comment: You may need to tell us more about your setup and environment. Also, we don't deliver answers "ASAP"; due to the very nature of Stack Exchange, sometimes the best answer come months or years after the question was asked.

Comment: I've some text files from which I've to extract only "borrower names" from all sentences. 

Ex: 
Credit Agreement  
Dated as of July 1, 2017 
among 
Hub Group, Inc. and
Hub City Terminals, Inc.,
as Borrowers,
........

I'm using Stanford's NER jar and classifiers in Java to classify all person names as "PERSON". I have to extract only borrower details from all other names

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Knowledge Extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_extraction), a task that goes far beyond Named Entity Recognition. It is an area of ongoing research, don't expect ready-made tools for this right now.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for your clarification. I'm a student experimenting on NLP.